# Selenium, Python - Trying to get to click the react-text tag or click the nth occurence of the class it belongs to leads to error 'no element found'

Tags: python, selenium, testing, beautifulsoup, automation

I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@style="Text_in_style"]')
```

but gives error no such element. I know the 'list-group-item report-item' position i want is 13th out of the 20, so can i somehow the 13th class name 'list-group-item report-item'? Thanks!

[As you can see both span style's have exactly similar structure below, only except for the span style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuWzw.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="list-group report-group-list"]')
buttons[3].click()
```

Thanks! google